# How to split WebSphere virtual hosts, single webserver for multiple JVMs

Tags: apache, websphere, virtualhost, ibmhttpserver

**How can I configure the virtual hosts to send the right url to the right JVM, when all of the apps use the same context root?**

eg:

- https://app1.mydomain.com/myapp -> app1 JVM
- https://app2.mydomain.com/myapp -> app2 JVM
- https://app3.mydomain.com/myapp -> app3 JVM

**Info**

I have multiple JVMs, and all apps have the same context root:

- app1 (context root: /myapp) (internal port: 9080)
- app2 (context root: /myapp) (internal port: 9081)
- app3 (context root: /myapp) (internal port: 9082)

I have one webserver:

- webserver1

I have multiple subdomains:

- app1.mydomain.com
- app2.mydomain.com
- app3.mydomain.com

Notes

- I'm trying to avoid using multiple IP addresses or webservers
- Running Websphere 9.0.0.6, IBM HTTP Server (Apache), Windows 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define three virtual hosts in WAS, each with the right non-wildcard host aliases and map each respective application to its virtualhost,  the generated plugin-cfg.xml will route the way you want.

Comment: This is the correct answer, each different host should contain the port (443) and the domain (subdomain.mydomain.com)  rather than just *